# Python code for Align selected to active

Tags: python, scripting

I have one object selected, and another object is active.
What is the python code for *Object>Transform>Align Selected to Active*? (requires the addon *Object: Align Tools* that ships with Blender.)

Also is there a way to force the python Consol to echo all commands?

Any help greatfully received.

Comment: Did not understand, please explain.

Comment: There is no menu entry *Object > Transform > Align Selected to Active*, is it? There is *Cltr+S (Snap) > Selection to Active*. The console echos all commands by default => bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_active()

Comment: In object mode under the object menu, then the transform menu the option at the bottom is Align Selected to Active.

(You may need to have the objects align addon active, I don't know.)

When you click this option nothing gets output from the python consol.

Comment: I get this error 
Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_active.poll() failed, context is incorrect

When I force the context to be 'VIEW_3D'

in matches the location ut not the rotation. When I use the menu option it matches both location and rotation

Comment: @MattL Ah thanks! Indeed the addon *Object: Align Tools* must be active. Otherwise, the mentioned menu entry doesn't exist.

Comment: The python consol definately doesn't echo all commands. 
When you select an object for example the consol echos nothing

Answer (score 1):

[bpy.ops.object.align](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.align)

For example:

```py
bpy.ops.object.align(bb_quality=True, align_mode='OPT_3', relative_to='OPT_1', align_axis={'X', 'Y', 'Z'})
```

As a general tip, after using an operator, go to the *Scripting* workspace and look at the *Info* panel [image] on bottom left - the operator is usually there:

[image]

Comment: Just a **warning**: The in the question mentioned addon *Object: Align Tools* seems to overwrite the operator (Blender 3.3). When it's active the menu entry *Object > Transform > Align Objects* is replaced by *Object > Transform > Align Selected to Active*. If you enable the addon it replaces the operator. Then you will get an error if you try to call the operator as shown above. If you disable the addon it removes the menu entry + operator and it's gone! You get a "not found" error when you try to execute the line shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.
This is starting to drive me a bit mad... I'm trying to write a super simple script that creates an empty and matches the position and rotation of a select object (or multiple objects)
Your example almost works for the position, but the original selected object moves ( I want it to stay where it is) 
Any ideas?

Comment: @MattL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem Maybe you just want to [parent](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html) your object or use a [constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/index.html)?

Comment: I'd like this code to work for bones too constraining bones in blender is no easy task

Comment: Ok, here's the long question.

I'm trying to write a Nullifier script.

Nullifier was a command in Softimage 3D that would 'pin' an object(s) in space and allow you to move that objects parent around without moving the pinned object. Or ( in the case of a rig) Allow you to pin the hand effector to a table for example.
I've written this same tool in both XSI and Maya but in Blender seems to be a bit more complicated....